# What Python modules are required to properly read a binary file according to it's specs?

Tags: python, binary, file-format

I have a binary file which is specified as "the file contains four fields. Each field is preceded by a 4-byte integer field that specifies its length."

What are the modules, that I need to take a look at in order to be able to read the four segments individually? I tried to open the file in binary mode and read the first 4 elements to get the size of the first field like so:

```
with open('file', 'rb') as in_file:
    lengthFirstField = in_file.read()[0:4]
    print(lengthFirstField)
```

But I guess that's wrong because I get four \x00 values which equals 0?

What is the proper way to do something like this?

Comment: Maybe the first field's length is just 0.

Comment: FYI _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more_ is likely to get closed.

Comment: You can use the `struct` module to convert 4 bytes into an integer.  You'd need to look at the spec of your binary file to see what a length of zero means.

Comment: The struct module should be sufficient